# Company name for Android App

Tags: android, publishing

Okay... I hate that I'm asking it here... but I just don't know where else to go. I'm simply an independent developer hoping to release an android app in the near future. I have already registered as a developer with Google Play. I also have a website with my made-up developer name.

So... can I simply name my application package whatever I like, and splatter my app with my made up company name, i.e. have a splash screen saying "My Cool Developer Studio?" I don't have a tax id or actual business of any kind.

Comment: Off topic, but it probably depends on if you want any legal protection of your brand.

Comment: You are free to do as you please. Different countries have different tax ramifications, and in the US you're required to report income over a certain amount to the IRS. But there are no restrictions set forth by Google, they are far more lenient than Apple. Apple on the otherhand you have to have your tax papers and contracts all in effect.

Comment: @Mike... I know... I'm just abusing the fact that I'm certain someone on SO will know.

Comment: @Amit So I gather... if an app makes enough, I'd just be reporting as my own personal income so it gets taxed.

Comment: If it makes enough to be deemed taxable income. You can of course show losses for a few years to the IRS. Which means if you get a business license (costs 10-30$) and do a sole proprietor business model, your tax id is your social, which is your own personal income. But you can write off a bunch of things, like your machine, your domicile, your car, pending their depreciation is substantially attributed to your company/business. General rule of thumb < 10K income don't bother, anything above you report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are free to do as you please. Different countries have different tax ramifications, and in the US you're required to report income over a certain amount to the IRS. But there are no restrictions set forth by Google, they are far more lenient than Apple. Apple on the otherhand you have to have your tax papers and contracts all in effect.

Comment: Thank you for all of the responses, albeit being totally inappropriate for this forum.

Comment: Agreed, inappropriate maybe, but relevant, 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Google cares unless you are doing something wrong (impersonating someone,etc.).

And I'm not sure what your local tax laws are, but in Canada you can make up a name and operate under it without a lot of fuss as long as do certain income tax related things.

I think it matters more about your local tax/regulatory situation than Google cares.

Answer (score 0):

Should not be a problem. A business is only needed for tax reasons when making a profit. Same applies for both appstore & play.